# OSX Yosemite getutxent() returning the same user twice

Tags: c, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I am trying to get a list of current logged in users using the `getutxent()` function defined in apple's `<utmpx.h>`. The test code I am using is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmpx.h>

int main(void) {
    setutxent();
    while (1) {
        struct utmpx *user_info = getutxent();
        if (user_info == NULL) break;
        printf("%s\n", user_info->ut_user);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am testing it with only one logged in user. The output I get is this:

```
myusername
myusername
```

Why does my username appear twice? Would that happen if there were multiple users?

Details about my mac:
[image]

Comment: Yosemite is only a beta product. This may be a known issue which is fixed in the final release. I suggest asking this in the Apple Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getutxent()` doesn't report users, it reports sessions.

If you have multiple sessions open (for example, a terminal session), it will be logged in the user accounting database and retrieved blindly. You can verify this by checking the `ut_id` and `ud_line` elements of the `utmpx` structure. They should be different for each instance where `ut_user` is the same, as they inhabit separate processes (and terminals, if you're using that).